# Why does IE8 display a whitespace GAP between my menu bar and page content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

[The page in question](http://truxmap.com)

Please open the page in whatever browser you normally use and confirm that the menu bar immediately precedes the map.  Next, open the page in IE8 and see that it inserts whitespace (roughly the height of the menu bar).  Even if you use IE7, the whitespace doesn't appear.  This has been bothering me for a while and I haven't been able to find an adequate solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be the <br style="clear: left">? Try adding a height: 0 to it

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. that was something that slipped past me as a possible cause for the error.  alas, after setting the height to 0 i was able to determine that that wasnt the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you want us to debug obfuscated javascript? :-)

All I can tell you is that

1) You're not using the (Google Maps v2) recommended DOCTYPE with a Strict DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Ref: [Google Maps API V2 Doc.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps)

That will switch IE into "Standards Compliant Mode" (According to Microsoft, anyway)

2) Try using the IE7 compatibility tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

That must be the first META tag and before any CSS.
Even MS' own Bing maps use it. :-)

Comment: yea youre right i should have been clear: i think its a problem with my html, not the GWT code.  as for the strict dtd doctype, i removed that a while ago because it was causing an issue with jquery ui and i decided removing it would be easier than keeping it doing further troubleshooting.  im going to be trying both of your suggestions and ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: The meta tag was just what I needed... thanks.  Is there any reason to change the doc type if everything appears to be working as id like it to in all browsers?

Comment: @culov - Since the Google Maps API V2 is now deprecated, (which means that no new features will be added to it and the code will not change), I'd say that if it all works as expected then there's no need to add the Strict DTD. (If it ain't broken don't fix it). :-) If you ever decide to add GPolylines or GPolygons to the map then you might need it. --- BTW, I've noticed another minor glitch with the topbar: If you resize the browser window to a certain width the topbar fails to adjust itself. (both in IE and Firefox). Try resizing it one bit at a time until things don't fit in one single line.

Answer (score 1):

U wanna try the IE compatibility view? 
I have no issue after using that.
I tested w/o compatibility view and saw the space

Answer (score 0):

You have not explicitly set margins for header tags but you are using them in some of the supposedly hidden elements up there near your header.  This should fix your issue:

```
h2 { margin: 0; }
```